# How to prevent blocked login on gmail for play developer console test account

Tags: android, playback, google-developers-console

On Play developer console we are required to submit test account for play reviewer to review our app.

While our app is using gmail signing, then we submit gmail username nand password to it.

The problem is, while their reviewer / robot trying to signing and test our app, i got notification that there is signing attempt on that gmail account and google blocked it, how to fix this ?
To make app review run easily

Thanks.

Comment: I accidentally came here again from Google search results, because I had the same problem. for someone got this case, you can create a fresh gmail account every update app to handle this issue.